# XSLT convert flat structure to array

Tags: arrays, xslt, flat

Here's source XML:

```
<customers>
    <firstname1>Sean</firstname1>
    <lastname1>Killer</lastname1>
    <sex1>M</sex1>
    <firstname2>Frank</firstname2>
    <lastname2>Woods</lastname2>
    <sex2>M</sex2>
    <firstname3>Jennifer</firstname3>
    <lastname3>Lee</lastname3>
    <sex3>F</sex3>
</customers>
```

How can I convert it to this?

```
<MyCustomers>
    <Customer>
        <Name> Sean Killer</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name> Frank Woods</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>Jennifer Lee</Name>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
    </Customer>
</MyCustomers>
```

Comment: Please use the `code` markup and overthink your posting.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most generic and flexible solution using XSLT 1.0. It produces the wanted result even when the children of the top element are re-shuffled in arbitrary way. :)

Comment: What answer are you going to accept then?

Answer (score 4):

As per comments:

> *what if elements were not in consequent orders?*

In this case (assuming XSLT 1.0) you can use `translate()` to get the id of the elements and then search for the corresponding elements by correct name built using `concat()`. I would change the `following-sibling::` axis to the `../` (short for `parent::`) to make sure to eventually catch also elements preceding the current `firstname`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="customers">
        <MyCustomers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(),'firstname')]"/>
        </MyCustomers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'firstname')]">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="translate(name(),'firstname','')"/>

        <Customer>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ',
                    ../*[name()=concat('lastname',$id)])"/></Name>
            <Sex><xsl:value-of select="../*[name()=concat('sex',$id)]"/></Sex>
        </Customer>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Obsolete answer**

Assuming the fixed input document structure as shown in the question, a fine working XSLT 1.0 transform is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="customers">
        <MyCustomers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(),'firstname')]"/>
        </MyCustomers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'firstname')]">
        <Customer>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ',
                    following-sibling::*[1]
                    [starts-with(name(),'lastname')])"/></Name>
            <Sex><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[2]
                    [starts-with(name(),'sex')]"/></Sex>
        </Customer>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Little explanation**

You need XPath 1.0 function `starts-with()` because of the sad name of the tags in your XML input. You can use the `following-sibling::` axis to get the required following sibling tags of any element whose name starts with `firstname`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about if the elements are not in consequent orders:<customers>
 <firstname1>Sean</firstname1>
 <firstname2>Frank</firstname2>
 <lastname1>Killer</lastname1>
 <sex1>M</sex1>
 <lastname2>Woods</lastname2>
 <firstname3>Jennifer</firstname3>
 <lastname3>Lee</lastname3>
 <sex3>F</sex3>
 <sex2>M</sex2>
</customers>

Comment: If the elements are not in consequent order, your sample input does not reflect appropriately your real XML. However, if the elements are not in consequent order, how can you know for example a certain `sex` tag belongs to a certain `firstname`? Can you be more clear please?

Comment: I see now, you mean depending by the integer appended in the element name?

Comment: @sean - see my answer for an XSLT 2.0 solution. Hopefully you're able to use 2.0.

Comment: @empo - I like how you used `translate()` instead of something like `substring()`. +1

Comment: @empo: `translate()` isn't necessary at all in this solution and results in inefficiency. You can just use `substring(name(), 9)`. Also, on an arbitrary reshuffling, your solution produces customers that are not ordered by the "id" that comes at the end of the element name. In My answer I do this in a very simple way. :)

Comment: @Dimitre: your answers is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dimitre you are (obviously) right. I did not care about sorting (not mentioned as a requirement in the OP's question) _and_ `translate()` might result in a (little) inefficiency. However I'm not going to change an answer which generated forty reps. :)) . The OP can easily tune it by applying sort (if required) and change `translate()` with `substring()` (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that will get the output you're looking for, even if they aren't in order. It also sorts by the "firstname" element names.

**Sample XML input (mixed up to show different ordering):**

```
<customers>
  <lastname1>Killer</lastname1>
  <sex3>F</sex3>
  <firstname2>Frank</firstname2>
  <firstname1>Sean</firstname1>
  <lastname2>Woods</lastname2>
  <sex2>M</sex2>
  <firstname3>Jennifer</firstname3>
  <sex1>M</sex1>
  <lastname3>Lee</lastname3>
</customers>
```

**XSLT 2.0 stylesheet (tested with Saxon-HE 9.3):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name()[starts-with(.,'firstname')]">
        <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring(name(),10)"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$suffix"/></xsl:message>
        <customer>
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ',/customers/*[starts-with(name(),'lastname')][ends-with(name(),$suffix)])"/>  
          </Name>
          <Sex>
            <xsl:value-of select="/customers/*[starts-with(name(),'sex')][ends-with(name(),$suffix)]"/>
          </Sex>
        </customer>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='customers'">
        <MyCustomers>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="name()[starts-with(.,'firstname')]"></xsl:sort>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </MyCustomers>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<MyCustomers>
   <customer>
      <Name>Sean Killer</Name>
      <Sex>M</Sex>
   </customer>
   <customer>
      <Name>Frank Woods</Name>
      <Sex>M</Sex>
   </customer>
   <customer>
      <Name>Jennifer Lee</Name>
      <Sex>F</Sex>
   </customer>
</MyCustomers>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation produces the wanted result even when the children of the top element are shuffled in any arbitrary way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumCustomers"
      select="count(/*/*) div 3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <MyCustomers>
       <xsl:for-each select=
           "*[not(position() > $vNumCustomers)]">
         <xsl:variable name="vNum" select="position()"/>

         <Customer>
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select=
             "concat(/*/*[name()=concat('firstname',$vNum)],
                     ' ',
                     /*/*[name()=concat('lastname',$vNum)]
                     )
             "/>
          </Name>
          <Sex>
            <xsl:value-of select=
             "/*/*[name()=concat('sex',$vNum)]
             "/>
          </Sex>
         </Customer>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </MyCustomers>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** ( an arbitrary re-shuffling of the provided one):

```
<customers>
    <sex1>M</sex1>
    <lastname2>Woods</lastname2>
    <lastname1>Killer</lastname1>
    <sex2>M</sex2>
    <firstname3>Jennifer</firstname3>
    <firstname2>Frank</firstname2>
    <lastname3>Lee</lastname3>
    <firstname1>Sean</firstname1>
    <sex3>F</sex3>
</customers>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<MyCustomers>
   <Customer>
      <Name>Sean Killer</Name>
      <Sex>M</Sex>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <Name>Frank Woods</Name>
      <Sex>M</Sex>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <Name>Jennifer Lee</Name>
      <Sex>F</Sex>
   </Customer>
</MyCustomers>
```

**Explanation**:

1. We compute the number of customers whose data is presented. The variable `$vNumCustomers` holds this data.
2. For each customer{i} (i = 1 to `$vNumCustomers`) we create the corresponding `<Customer{i}>` element. In order to avoid using recursion, we use **[the Piez method](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e300)** here.

Comment: I like the idea of "count(/*/*) div 3", but this may not work if the source xml contains other irrelevant elements, like: <Customers><date>2011-07-11</date><firstname1/><lastname1/>......<Customers>

Comment: @sean: Of course. There is a much more general solution, I only need to find some free time to fit it into my answer. My current answer was produced in a spare 5 minutes.

Comment: I appreciate that. BTW, which solution you preferred? Is this for-each loop solution or the template match solution?

Comment: @Dimitre: I really like your `count(/*/*) div 3`, but it might cause problems when one of the (three) elements is missing. For test, try to remove `sex2` from the input and the output produced by this transform will miss the target. Try with my own, and the wanted output will be preserved.

Comment: @Sean: there no perfect answers, even if @Dimitre ones usually shave perfection.